# Getting Top Values from One Sheet and inputting onto a different sheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula

So I'm going to eventually have 3 sheets. Sheet 1 is where I have data (numbers for a category and a name associated with it. Sheet 2 is where I pull the top 5 users for each category. Sheet 3 is where I have a leaderboard for points gained.

Right now I'm trying to work with Sheet 2 (grab the top 5 performers from each category. I'm fairly new to Excel, but after some research it seemed that XLOOKUP would be the way to go. (i'll attach screenshots below.

I'm using this formula:

```
=XLOOKUP(LARGE('Cases Test for Categories'!$C$18:$C$55,1),'Cases Test for Categories'!$C$18:$C$55,'Cases Test for Categories'!$A$18:$A$55)
```

however when using it I get all 0's.

[image]

Here's a screenshot of values I'm trying to grab from "Warranty Service Request"

and here is a screenshot when applying my formula

[image]

The solution I would want is to grab the 5 largest numbers from sheet 1 with the person name as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that XLOOKUP can get you anywhere near what you want but the formula below will get you one step closer.

```
=INDEX(List,MATCH(LARGE(INDEX(List, ,2),1),INDEX(List,,2),0),1)
```

In fact, it's the explanation of that formula which will be of help. Here we go.

- `List` is a named range, perhaps equal to your *'Cases Test for Categories'!$C$18:$C$55*. The reason for using a name is obvious. It's shorter. In my test List = A2:B6, in case you want to reconstruct it. Column 1 has names, column 2 numbers.
- The term `INDEX(List,,2)` specifies the second column of *List*. You can replace the '2' with a formula to specify different columns of the named range.
- In fact, `INDEX(List,,1)` does specify the first column and `INDEX(List,4,1)` specifies the 4th cell in that column, and that is exactly what you see in my formula. All of *MATCH(LARGE(INDEX(List, ,2),1),INDEX(List,,2),0)* just serves to find the row number in *List*, in this example the number 4.
- Of course, `LARGE(INDEX(List, ,2),1)` returns the largest number in column2 of *List*. The '1' can be replaced by a formula, for example `ROW()-1` which would return 1 if placed in row 2 and count up from there as it's copied down. Try `=ROW()-1` in any cell in row 2 and copy the formula down.
- *MATCH([LARGEST],INDEX(List,,2),0)* returns the row number where the largest was found, and that is the number we need to return the name from the first column of *List*.

This will work perfectly for one column and can easily be modified to work for different columns. Your question doesn't specify how you would like to arrange the 5 results from each category but the formula can be modified a little to accommodate whatever you want. What it can *not* do is to deal with ties. *MATCH(LARGE* can only find the first of several identical results.

To break ties in this sort of operation is complicated and must be done ether by helper columns in the data table or using VBA. It's definitely the topic of another question. For now I hope that it's a problem you will not have to anticipate.

Comment: a bit after i posted this i solved it before getting off work! thanks for the explanation!